# dpkg still thinks corrupted upgrade of Textadept pending - how to clean up?

Tags: apt, dpkg

Yesterday I attempted to upgrade my installation of the [Textadept editor](http://foicica.com/textadept/) in my Linux Mint 13 ("Maya") LTS Xfce 32-bit system (based on Ubuntu 12.04 Precise). I get this via the [WebUpd8 PPA](http://ppa.webupd8.org/post/109969969531/textadept-7-8-available-in-ppa), and have done for some time (this is pretty routine).

However, I must have got a corrupted download (see various [error code/log entries](http://pastebin.com/hJW91BJq)), and the upgrade failed. In fact, the Textadept install disappeared from my system. (It lives in `/opt/textadept`, and this vanished. The icon was still present on my dock bar, but gone from the system menu.)

After trying various "fixes" (like `apt-get purge`, and starting over) all with the same results -- the system thinking I have a corrupt download -- I simply downloaded the `textadept_LATEST.i386.tgz` file from [Foicica.com](http://foicica.com/textadept/), and bunged it into `/opt/textadept` myself. Works just fine!

Except -- apt (?) still thinks I have a corrupt download pending, and keeps giving the same error message:

```
...
Setting up textadept (7.8-1~webupd8~1) ...
Downloading...
--2015-02-04 19:53:00--  http://foicica.com/textadept/download/textadept_7.8.i386.tgz
Resolving foicica.com (foicica.com)... 97.107.131.154, 2600:3c03::f03c:91ff:fedf:511e
Connecting to foicica.com (foicica.com)|97.107.131.154|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 416 Requested Range Not Satisfiable

    The file is already fully retrieved; nothing to do.

Download done.
Removing outdated cached downloads...
sha256sum mismatch textadept_7.8.i386.tgz
TextAdept is NOT installed.
dpkg: error processing textadept (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Setting up libmagic1 (5.09-2ubuntu0.6) ...
Setting up file (5.09-2ubuntu0.6) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin ...
ldconfig deferred processing now taking place
Errors were encountered while processing:
 textadept
```

How do I tell the system to forget about this particular upgrade? or clean up after this glitch properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, is dpkg which thinks (rightly so) that your package isn't correctly installed, because the configuration was never done in first place (which is why it says "half-configured"). You must check your `/var/cache/textadept` directory (as stated in .postinst script), find and delete the package, so it downloads it correctly and it gets installed using dpkg. The package is badly done, which is why you have these kind of problems, for which I recommend using the manual method instead.

In summary:

```
sudo rm -r /var/cache/textadept
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

That should allow dpkg to configure the package. Now, you need to decide, if you want to use the repository supplied package or remove/purge it so you can manually manage it.

Comment: Thanks - helpful! And fixed. :) Where would I find that `.postinst` script? I looked on PPA, but can't find code, and it's not in the `/var/cache/textadept` dir either. (And thanks too for tidying my question!)

Comment: @Davïd the textadept.tar.xz package has the source. It also resides in `/var/lib/dpkg/info/textadept.postinst`